# Call by reference value's type casting in Unix

Tags: c, unix, casting, porting

While I debug my minor porting program, I have question about type casting differences.

Here is my source (below) :

```
  1 #include <time.h>
  2 #include <stdio.h>
  3 
  7 int main () {
  8     clock_t now; //unsigned long 
  9     struct tm * mac_time; // const long
 10     char *time_str;
 11     now = time (NULL);
 12     mac_time = localtime((const long *)&now); 
 13                           // localtime ( const long <- unsigned long)
 13     time_str = asctime(mac_time);
 14     printf("Now : %s\n",time_str);
 15     return 0;
 16 }
```

First, it works properly, there's no error right now. But I have a question about type casting difference.

In line 12, since type casting warning has occurred, I changed the value's type for debug.

but what is the difference between

```
12     mac_time = localtime((const long *)&now);
```

and

```
12     mac_time = localtime(&(const long *)now);
```

I thought there's no difference to each other, because this is only different from 'casted value's address and 'value's address casted'.

But complier throws out warning message latter one.

Will you give me some advice for this type casting issue?

Comment: Well, what is the warning message?

Comment: Here is my error: `UNIX_porting.c:9:23: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'const long *'
        mac_time = localtime(&(const long *)now);` @OliCharlesworth

Comment: First one: "now" is a value, u need to convert it to pointer (using &). Then you cast this pointer to const long *.

Comment: Note that in any case you should be using a time_t and not a clock_t(nor should you have any cast to long*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case

```
mac_time = localtime((const long *)&now);
```

you are casting `&now`, which is of `pointer to clock_t` type, to `const long *`, i.e, pointer to `const long` type. No problem if `localtime` expecting argument of type `pointer to const long` type. While in second case

```
 mac_time = localtime(&(const long *)now);
```

`now` is of `clock_t` and you are casting it to `const long *` and then trying to pass its address to the function and the compiler is showing you error.
Now about the error:

```
error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'const long *' mac_time = localtime(&(const long *)now);
```

You should note that casting produce an [r-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29). On the other hand `&` require an l-value as an operand. That's why you can't do `&(const long *)now` and compiler is throwing the error.

And finally note that **there is no call by reference in C instead all calls are by value**.

Comment: To sum up with your opinion, `&(const long *)now` is pointing value's size, which amount of `(const long *)`. And `(const long *)&now` points now's casted address, right?

Comment: `(const long *)&now`: Casting address of `now`. `&(const long *)now`: casting `now` to a pointer then passing its address.

Comment: @Sogo; There was some typo. I updated my answer. Please read it now.

Comment: Thanks haccks!! The last answer that you replied really really help me a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

`(const long *)&now` takes the address of `now` and interprets it as an address of a `const long`.

`&(const long *)now` interprets `now` as an address of a `const long` and takes the address of that address. This is dangerous, because you are basically converting an integer or float to a pointer without any justification as to why the memory location identified by `now` is accessible to your application.

Comment: I appreciate of your help Oswald! Your answer is much more intuitive!

Answer (score 4):

The pointer cast is completely unnecessary. If your program appears to work, it's an unlucky coincidence. (I say "unlucky" because it means the error is not being diagnosed.)

`localtime()` takes an argument of type `const time_t*`, *not* `clock_t*`. `time_t` and `clock_t` are distinct types, used for different purposes, even though they *might* happen to be defined in the same way in some particular implementation.

Change the definition of `now` to:

```
time_t now;
```

and call `localtime` like this:

```
mac_time = localtime(&now);
```

Any cast, especially a pointer cast, should be viewed with suspicion. Casts are too often used to silence compiler warnings, when the real solution is to fix your code so things are declared with the correct type in the first place.

As for the question you're asking -- well, it doesn't matter much, since the code is fundamentally incorrect. This:

```
mac_time = localtime((const long *)&now)
```

takes the address of `now` (which, in your code, is of type `clock_t*`) and converts it to `const long*`. Since `localtime` expects an argument of type `const time_t*`, and *apparently* `time_t` is defined as `long` on your implementation, this *appears* to work.

This:

```
mac_time = localtime(&(const long *)now);
```

takes the *value* of `now` (which at this point has not been initialized) and converts it to a `const long*`; in other words, it takes a garbage numeric value and converts it to a pointer. It then attempts to take the address of that pointer -- but since it's a pointer *value*, not a pointer *object*, it has no address. The above is a compile-time error. (I'd expect your compiler to treat this as a fatal error, not just a warning.)

But forget all that. Just declare your objects to be of the correct types in the first place, and you won't have to worry about casts.

(There are cases where casts, even pointer casts, are necessary and appropriate, but not for what you're trying to do here.)